# Json estructura propia con doble etiqueta de encabezado c#

Tags: c#, json, serialización, jsonobject, clase-anidada

estoy intentando generar el siguiente Json con la estructura a continuación:

```
{ 
   "Ticket":{ 
      "DevInfo":{ 
         "DevId":"00005857",
         "DescState":"Se solicita de su amable colaboracion brindando estimado de atencion"
      },
      "RefInfo":{ 
         "RefType":"AD02JKIJ",
         "RefId":"987654321"
      },
      "TrnState":{ 
         "State":"99353",
         "Desc":"F_L Oficina COD"
      },
      "IssDt":"07:03",
      "ClientDt":"2020-02-19"
   }
}
```

Tengo la siguiente clase generada a partir del Json.

```
public class DevInfo
{
    public string DevId { get; set; }
    public string DescState { get; set; }
}

public class RefInfo
{
    public string RefType { get; set; }
    public string RefId { get; set; }
}

public class TrnState
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public DevInfo DevInfo { get; set; }
    public RefInfo RefInfo { get; set; }
    public TrnState TrnState { get; set; }
    public string IssDt { get; set; }
    public string ClientDt { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

Pero cuando realizo la configuración para generar la estructura sólo consigo generar la siguiente estructura, la cuál no contiene la Etiqueta "Ticket":{, cuando intento añadirla aparece con un null, pero no abriendo la estructura.

```
{
  "DevInfo": {
    "DevId": "00000709",
    "DescState": "lkjoijrjwbehsb"
  },
  "RefInfo": {
    "RefType": "D00SI0S",
    "RefId": "20138939"
  },
  "TrnState": {
    "State": "Sty0111    ",
    "Desc": "Fuera de Servicio"
  },
  "IssDt": "08:08:00",
  "ClientDt": "2020-03-02"
}
```

Como ven la etiqueta '''"Ticket":{''', no logró incluirla.  El código que estoy usando para generar la estructura es el siguiente:

```
  oUser = (from d in db.WAPI_DATA_RUTA
  select d).ToList();

    foreach (var oElement in oUser)
    {

    Ticket jsonObject = new Ticket();

    {

        jsonObject.DevInfo = new DevInfo
        {   
            DevId = oElement.ATM,
            DescState = oElement.COMENTARY
        };

        jsonObject.RefInfo = new RefInfo
        {
            RefType = oElement.INCIDENT,
            RefId = oElement.TICKET
        };

        jsonObject.TrnState = new TrnState
        {
            State = oElement.STATUS_CODE,
            Desc = oElement.STATUS_CODE_DESC
        };

        jsonObject.IssDt = oElement.HOUR_INIT;
        jsonObject.ClientDt = oElement.DATE_INIT;
    };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, Formatting.Indented);

    }
```

Qué podría estar omitiendo, lo cual hace que no pueda generar la estructura correcta.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Debes crear un objeto RootObject en lugar de  Ticket jsonObject = new Ticket();  a ese objeto RootObjet agrega elementos Tickets y serializar el objeto rootObject que contiene elementos derivados Tickets

Comment: Muchas gracias estaba haciéndome un 8 por tan simple solución, me dio el foco para añadir lo que me faltaba y ya me funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta gracias a Miguel Zarate:

```
RootObject jsonObject = new RootObject();


                    {
                        jsonObject.Ticket = new Ticket
                        {

                        };
                        jsonObject.Ticket.DevInfo = new DevInfo
                        {   
                            DevId = oElement.ATM,
                            DescState = oElement.COMENTARY
                        };

                        jsonObject.Ticket.RefInfo = new RefInfo
                        {
                            RefType = oElement.INCIDENT,
                            RefId = oElement.TICKET
                        };

                        jsonObject.Ticket.TrnState = new TrnState
                        {
                            State = oElement.STATUS_CODE,
                            Desc = oElement.STATUS_CODE_DESC
                        };

                        jsonObject.Ticket.IssDt = oElement.HOUR_INIT;
                        jsonObject.Ticket.ClientDt = oElement.DATE_INIT;
                    };

                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, Formatting.Indented);
```